# Is it possible to make a Raspberry Pi transmit FM on several frequencies at the same time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, radio, frequency-modulation

I have read a few questions here on transmitting on multiple frequencies at the same time. But all of them was about transmitting the same signal to all frequencies.

The PiFM and [PiTX](https://github.com/F5OEO/rpitx) projects are examples of how to transmit audio over FM with no additional parts, including RDS data. This got me thinking. If I can receive multiple audio streams with my PI (say 5 different netradio stations), is it possible to somehow multiplex these on 5 different frequencies (say 100-105MHz) just modulating one pin on the PI, the same way PiFM works?

The end goal of this project would be to create a DAB-interface for a car stereo only supporting FM. I don't want any of the current solutions (external interface with single frequency FM transmitter, bluetooth, usb, etc). I would feed the antenna somehow directly into the cars antenna interface, hopefully stopping any transmission beyond my own car, while keeping nice strength for the FM radio.

Comment: The PiTX seems like a cool bit of code.  If I had to guess I would think it unable to handle very many simultaneous modulated RF signals.  There may be a user following that could be asked about the capabilities.  However your car radio will be happy with a single carrier and you just change the program material in your RPi, obviously your girlfriend will not think she has time warped into the 50's in you restored T-Bird if she cannot press the channel selects on the unmodified radio.  Worst case you could use 5 RPis and just use a passive resistor network to mix the signals for the ant input.

Comment: Yes I could just use a single carrier, but then it's just a rube goldberg dab->fm solution. I don't want to control it externally at all. I want "all" dab channels to show up on my head-units list of detected FM-stations.